# Slingshot (wingpanel) command - LOKI

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, slingshot

Does anyone know how to launch Slingshot (wingpanel) from the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

```
wingpanel --toggle-indicator app-launcher
```

Comment: Beautiful!, is there a way to launch it without the animation?

Comment: no, it's the normal GTK popover animation. So maybe systemwide...